# Does Torricelli's law assume constant height?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, flow, bernoulli-equation

I am planning on doing an experiment where I derive the optimal height for a hole in a container filled with water so that the stream travels the furthest. In order to determine this, I am planning on using Torricelli's law (V = √2gh) to determine the initial velocity, then by using the distance traveled and the time elapsed (time for the stream to touch the ground), I can determine a relationship between h/(H-h) and R, thus finding a general rule for other situations.

[image]

My question is: Does Torricelli's law assume that the height is constant, or does it only use the initial height of the water?

Comment: This may help;https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli's_law#Horizontal_distance_covered_by_the_jet_of_liquid

Comment: image; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli's_law#/media/File:TorricelliLawDiagram.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torricelli's law applies at each height. As the height $h$ changes, the velocity $v$ of the water coming out of the hole also changes, and along with this so does the range $R$.

This means that if the cross-sectional area $a$ of the hole is comparable with the cross-sectional area $A$ of the water tank, then both $h$ and $R$ are likely to change while you try to measure them. If you start by measuring $h$ then by the time you measure $R$ the value of $h$ will have changed.

To get round this you could make $A \gg a$. Then $h$ and $R$ will change slowly, giving you time to measure both approximately at the same time.

There is actually no need to measure $v$ at all. Simply record $h$ vs $R$ and plot $h/H$ vs $R$. Although $H$ also varies there is no need to measure it because $H=h+Y$ where $Y$ is the height of the hole above the base, which is constant.

What you can use Torricelli's Law for is to predict the optimal value of $h/H$ then compare this with the value found in your experiment and try to explain any difference.

Note that the water below the level of the hole plays no part in this experiment (*or does it?*) so you can simply raise the water tank to a new height instead of looking for a taller tank. You can place the hole a few cm from the bottom of the tank. This makes the best use of the tank which you have got. Also, for the same value of $h$, the larger you make the value of $Y$ then the greater the value of $R$ which will result. This means that your proportional errors in measuring $R$ will be smaller.

Another technique is to make a video recording of the experiment, with one metre rule fixed beside the tank for reading water level and one along the ground for measuring $R$. Then you can make a truly simultaneous measurement of $h$ and $R$, and you can obtain a better measurement of the centre of the stream for $R$.

Comment: I changed the nature of my experiment slightly, so that I am calculating h/(H-h). Would this change have any effect on how the experiment is implemented?

Comment: No it will not make any difference to how the experiment is *implemented.* Neither will it make any difference to how the results are *analysed*. You were originally trying to find the value of $h/H$ for which the value of $R$ is maximum. But $h/Y=h/(H-h)$ vs $R$ should work just as well. ... By the way, if you are happy with my answer please up-vote or select as Best Answer. Thank you.